# Anyone else getting a 301 error when trying to access yahoo's intraday stock data API?

Tags: node.js, api, yahoo, finance

I am using the npm intraday package, and i recently noticed that whenever I call the intraday() function i get a 301 error as a response. Is anyone else having this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I currently receive status 200 using the API with the request:

> https://chartapi.finance.yahoo.com/instrument/1.0/NFLX/chartdata;type=quote;range=1d/csv

You can check the GitHub source for the [Intraday module](https://github.com/nickdesaulniers/intraday/blob/master/src/intraday.coffee) and test the API using either your browser or an application such as Postman.

If you're still having problems, check your local network for possible redirections.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP 301 isn't an error; it's a redirect.

It looks like the yahoo API is issuing now redirects from plain `http` to `https`. 
 Unfortunately, the module you're using makes a plain http request and does not handle HTTP redirects.

Given that this is a simple request, I recommend using a more fully-featured HTTP client like [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) instead of the specialized intraday module.